# Is it true that Hazrat Fatima (R.A) soul was taken by ALLAH Himself

Tags: sharia

[image]

Salam,

I have attached a file which is circulating through facebook alot these days. I would like to know that is the information provided in the file wrong ? because it is against the basic teachings of islam and if it is not wrong then isnt it a great sin? The file attached is a reference from Shaykh Ismail Haqqi.

(the attached file's translation)

> Rasool Mohammed's(PBUH) daughter Fatima (AS) when passed and Allah ordered Izrael to take her soul, he refused in honor that neither the sun has seen a hair of her head nor the moon nor the stars and nor any other angel. It is narrated that when he refused to do so Allah had done the task of taking soul of his beloved Mohammed's(PBUH) dauhter himself.

Reference: Book Tafseer Rooh-Al-Bayan 5:237

Answer (score 2):

This seems unnecessarily romantic and mythic to be true, and Islam is a clear and straightforward religion. However, if we assume for the sake of argument that it were true, who would have been there to report it? Remember that Sayyidatna Fatima died shortly after her father, peace be upon him. Who would have narrated this? Hope this helps.

Comment: @anas, it could be that its incorrectly referenced to the author, or it could be simply a mistake by him. Even if it's deliberate, it could be that he believes it for some reason or knows some logic behind that we either don't know or don't agree with. All the above possibilities mean that he hasn't performed any sin. Of course, there is the small possibility that he is deliberately misleading people, but I like to give people the benefit of the doubt, hoping that it will mean that I will receive the same courtesy some day (:

Comment: @Sohaeb if you are refering to the reference in the question then it is given in the picture i forgot to add it editing it right now so later when approved anyone can see.

Answer (score -3):

It's TRUE because in these Mohammed saw is absent, but he said that my followers will be divided into 73 sects. He told us about the day of judgement, etc. Maybe he saw told to anyone at that time. Actually, there are some issues in Islamic history. It is written in the era umayyad dynasty which were very against hashmi.

Comment: Your title question can't be answered, as after Muhammad there was no revelation nor should it if we accept him as the last prophet and messenger of Allah. And Fatima died after her father. Your question content hardly matches your question title.

Comment: Do you have any evidences supporting your claims that it is true?

Comment: Salam dear brother and sister, you people don't know about Islam history what happenedthere and who did atrocitiesin Islam, otherwise you won't aske me about my claim.